# Help with commutator algebra with fermionic operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator, fermions, anticommutator

I am struggling to understand how the following is true for the fermionic creation/annihilation operators $a^\dagger, a$: $$[a^\dagger a, a]=-a$$

If someone could walk me through the math derivation of this, I would greatly appreciate it!

I see that $[a^\dagger a, a]= a^\dagger aa - a a^\dagger a = (1-a a^\dagger)a - a a ^\dagger a = a - 2 a a^\dagger a$ but I'm not sure how to simplify this further to get $-a$ at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step was already good.
And then you can exploit $aa=0$.

$$\begin{align}
[a^\dagger a, a]
&=a^\dagger \underbrace{aa}_{=0}-aa^\dagger a \\
&=-aa^\dagger a \\
&=-a(1-aa^\dagger) \\
&=-a+\underbrace{aa}_{=0}a^\dagger \\
&=-a
\end{align}$$

Comment: $aa=0$ is only true for fermions because the max occupation number in a state is 1, right?

Comment: @photonica yes, it is only for fermions. $a^\dagger a^\dagger=0$ is because max occupation number is 1, and $aa=0$ is because min occupation number is 0.

Comment: @photonica This follows from the anti-commutation relations.